# Why does output come out from STDERR and not STDOUT when using child_process.exec for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, stdout, child-process

I am trying to buffer the results from my phantomjs script to nodejs but for some reason the buffer results is constantly coming out of STDERR but not STDOUT even though there doesn't seem to be an error.

NodeJS code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('phantomjs console.js', function(stdout, stderr, error){
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
        console.log("Standard Output: " + stdout + " ");
        console.log("Error Output: " + stderr + " ");
    });
```

PhantomJS code (console.js):

```
console.log("Hello world!");
phantom.exit();
```

Result that I get:

```
exec error: 
Standard Output: null 
Error Output: Hello world!
```

Comment: you have the formal params defined backwards: in node, errors come first.

Comment: Hi Dan, I even tried to switch the position of the console.log of stdout and stderr and still get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Dan Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106677/why-does-output-come-out-from-stderr-and-not-stdout-when-using-child-process-exe#comment39071528_25106677), you have `error`, `stderr`,  and `stdout` switched - not the `console.log` statements, but the order of the parameters in the function. Below is the correct order as per [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('phantomjs console.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
    console.log("Standard Output: " + stdout + " ");
    console.log("Error Output: " + stderr + " ");
});
```

The reason for your output was that your `stdout` was where the actual `error` should have been, so it was empty. Your `stderr` was in the position of the actual `stdout` so it recieved the output. Your `error` was in the position of the actual `stderr`, so it was empty.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I didn't know that the order of the parameters mattered but now I do.